# Can not update Windows 7 anymore

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-update

When i click "Install updates" progress bar shows up with "Preparing to install" text and it dissapears and again i see text about updates and button "Install updates".

I have no events written in event logs for the time when i click "install updates". The WindowsUpdate.txt log looks like this:

```
2015-05-10  00:10:22:304     352    7d8 AU  Launched new AU client for directive 'Download Approval', session id = 0x1
2015-05-10  00:10:22:314    3492    6e0 Misc    ===========  Logging initialized (build: 7.6.7601.18804, tz: +0200)  ===========
2015-05-10  00:10:22:314    3492    6e0 Misc      = Process: C:\Windows\system32\wuauclt.exe
2015-05-10  00:10:22:314    3492    6e0 AUClnt  Launched Client UI process
2015-05-10  00:10:23:934    2568    c88 WUApp   No EULA acceptance needed
2015-05-10  00:10:23:934     352    430 AU  AU received approval from Ux for 19 updates
2015-05-10  00:10:23:934     352    430 AU  AU setting pending client directive to 'Progress Ux'
2015-05-10  00:10:28:324    3492    6e0 Misc    ===========  Logging initialized (build: 7.6.7601.18804, tz: +0200)  ===========
2015-05-10  00:10:28:324    3492    6e0 Misc      = Process: C:\Windows\system32\wuauclt.exe
2015-05-10  00:10:28:324    3492    6e0 Misc      = Module: C:\Windows\system32\wucltux.dll
2015-05-10  00:10:28:324    3492    6e0 CltUI   FATAL: Failed to connect to AU engine to get notification handle, hr=80040155
2015-05-10  00:10:28:324     352    7d8 AU  AU received handle event
2015-05-10  00:10:28:324     352    7d8 AU  No featured updates notifications to show
2015-05-10  00:10:28:324     352    7d8 AU  UpdateDownloadProperties: 0 download(s) are still in progress.
2015-05-10  00:10:28:324     352    7d8 AU  Piggybacking on an AU detection already in progress
2015-05-10  00:10:28:324     352    7d8 AU  AU setting pending client directive to 'Install Complete Ux'
2015-05-10  00:10:28:324     352    7d8 AU  WARNING: Pending directive, 'Install Complete Ux', is not applicable
2015-05-10  00:10:28:324     352    7d8 AU  AU setting pending client directive to 'Download Approval'
2015-05-10  00:10:28:324     352    7d8 AU  Successfully wrote event for AU health state:0
2015-05-10  00:10:29:004     352    430 AU  WARNING: Returning due to error from GetDownloadProgressUx, error = 0x8024000C
2015-05-10  00:10:29:004     352    430 AU  WARNING: GetInteractiveInstallProgress failed, error = 0x8024000C
2015-05-10  00:10:29:004    2568    c88 WUApp   WARNING: Call to GetInteractiveInstallProgress failed, hr=8024000C
2015-05-10  00:10:29:004    2568    c88 WUApp   WARNING: Call to DeserializeInstallResults failed, hr=80243003
2015-05-10  00:10:29:004    2568    c88 WUApp   WARNING: Unable to display installation results, hr=80243003
```

My Windows is 64bit. I've tried multiple online solutions and no one did the work. How to repair Windows Update?

Comment: Your system files are corrupt run SFC to repair the damage

Comment: 0x8024000C = WU_E_NOOP (No operation was required) and 80243003 = WU_E_INSTALLATION_RESULTS_NOT_FOUND (The results of download and installation are not available;the operation may have failed to start.). Download the MSU updates from the download center or via this tool: http://www.wsusoffline.net/ and install them. Does this work?

Comment: @tomaszs Hello, Have you been able to solve this issue ?